# How to exec & kill external python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a python (pyqt5) GUI to collect user input, build a command line then start the external program (in python too source .py or .exe) and keep the ability to stop/kill the external program.

What are the possibilities to do so ? pro & con pls

Should i go for a :

1.

```py
subprocess.Popen("python Desktop/prog.py")
```

- pro: direct .py interface
- con: can i run an .exe with this?, can i control the subProcess to force the stop/kill?

2.

```py
exec(object[, globals[, locals]])
```

- pro: it start any .exe
- con: can i stop the process if needed ? or a system kill via PID ?

3.

```py
t = threading.Thread( target=???, args=() )
```

- pro: can be stopped via t.stop()
- cons: can i run an .exe with this?

or another solution available?

Comment: The GUI is irrelevant for this case, so you should not use the pyqt5 tag

Comment: Out of those, doesn’t only subprocess run external programs? And did you look at [the documentation of subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), which answers your question about controlling subprocesses?